# Retro text box issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, timeout, intervals

I made this function that takes a string and types it into a div letter by letter, and then you click anywhere in the div and it clears all the text and starts the next string in an array letter by letter (like an old gameboy games text box whenever a character talked). The only issue is if you click the div before the function is done typing the current string it won't skip to the next string it will just clear the div and continue the string on the letter it was on before it got cut off. I tried to get it to where if you clicked before it was done typing the array of the current string it wouldn't do anything using a timeout but it only applies it to the first string. So instead  I tried to make it skip to the next string instead of finishing the current one but I think because the string is split into an array I can't do that?

basically just want to get it to where if you click in the middle of a string from the var b array it either: doesn't do anything, skips to show the entire string, skips to the next string.

```js
//JavaScript file

var x = "";
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var a = 0;
var b = ["Hello", "My name is Colin", "I am an entry level web developer!"]
var c = b[a];
a++;

function text(x) {
  var x;
  var string = x;
  var stringArray = string.split("");
  var arrayLength = stringArray.length;
  // var arrayFinal = stringArray[stringArray.length - 1]
  var r = 0;

  setInterval(function nextLetter() {
    if (arrayLength > 0) {
      output.innerHTML += stringArray[r]
      r++
      arrayLength--
    }
  }, 50); //end interval

  setTimeout(function() {
    output.onclick = function() {
      output.innerHTML = ""
      text(b[a])
      a++
    }
  }, 50 * arrayLength); //end timeout

} //end function

text(c)
```

```css
/* Cascading Style Sheet */

* {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
  <div id="output"></div>
```

This is practice so tips are appreciated! Still trying to learn the basics to syntax and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) and [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)

and you had issues with empty string:

```
function text(x) {
   var stringArray = (typeof x === 'string' || x instanceof String)?x.split(""):[];
```

Minimum change:

```js
//JavaScript file

var output = document.getElementById('output');
var a = 0;
var b = ["Hello", "My name is Colin", "I am an entry level web developer!"]
var c = b[a];
a++;
var tId, iId;
function text(x) {
  var stringArray = (typeof x === 'string' || x instanceof String)?x.split(""):[];
  var arrayLength = stringArray.length;
  // var arrayFinal = stringArray[stringArray.length - 1]
  var r = 0;
  clearInterval(iId);
  iId= setInterval(function nextLetter() {
    if (arrayLength > 0) {
      output.innerHTML += stringArray[r]
      r++
      arrayLength--
    }
  }, 50); //end interval
  clearTimeout(tId);
  tId=setTimeout(function() {
    output.onclick = function() {
      output.innerHTML = ""
      text(b[a])
      a++
    }
  }, 50 * arrayLength); //end timeout

} //end function

text(c)
```

```css
/* Cascading Style Sheet */

* {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, does x?x.split(""):""; basically say if there is no x value then print "". Is this just a more elegant way of keeping an empty string on the end of the array?

Comment: It is to make sure x is a string. The x can be null, or undefined and still be converted to a string. I notice that any number not 0 will also give errors

Comment: I changed the test - you wanted an array, I did not convert x to an array if it was not a string